# Probability of success in Multiple Choice Questions

Tags: probability, combinatorics

When presented with a multiple choice question, where 3 options are correct out of 8 options available, what is the probability of randomly selecting all three correct options?

Would it be as simple as $\frac38$ (i.e. $37.5\%$) or would it be $\frac18\times\frac17\times\frac16 = 0.29\%$?

Comment: Also, detail: Are you *allowed* to answer exactly three of the eight?

Comment: See my comment following the answer of tommik.

Comment: This largely depends on your strategy: do you know beforehand that there are exactly three correct answers, and you choose exactly three answers to match? Or maybe you randomly choose whether to select or not select each answer like a series of coin flips? Without these details the question isn't really well-defined

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, let me clarify: You know there are exactly 3 correct options out of the possible 8 beforehand. You are only allowed to select 3 options. You have to make your selection of 3 options and then 'submit' your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret the question as: what is the probabilty to choose exactly the 3 correct answers among the possibile 8?

Thus the correct answer is

$$\frac{\binom{3}{3}\cdot\binom{5}{0}}{\binom{8}{3}}=\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{2}{7}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: +1: to your answer.  **To the OP**: note that tommik's answer actually provides two distinct ways of computing the probability.  The LHS method, is based on Combinatorics, where there are $\binom{3}{3} = 1$ way of selecting the correct group of $3$ items, and $\binom{8}{3} = 56$ different ways of selecting any $3$ items out of $(8)$.  Here, Combinations are used to emphasize that in both the numerator and denominator, the order that the $3$ items are selected is deemed irrelevant. ...see next comment.

Comment: **To the OP:** in the RHS of tommik's answer, you have that the chance of the first selection being one of the $3$ correct choices is $\displaystyle \frac{3}{8}$.  Then, there are $7$ choices left, of which only $2$ are correct.  Therefore, the chance that the next selection is one of the remaining correct choices is $\displaystyle \frac{2}{7}$.  What one can infer from all of this is that **algebraically**, the LHS computation is equivalent to the RHS computation.  That algebraic conclusion can be routinely manually confirmed.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to help. I very much appreciate it.

Comment: @tommik Thank you sorry I am new to this I believe I have now accepted your answer. Apologies.